# Is it possible to redirect a client to another domain via GET after a POST request was submitted without using JavaScript? (OAUTH issue) (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I've tried using header() to redirect the user, however this only works in a GET request. When using an ajax POST request however the user is not redirected.

I know I could use the return of a status code to have ajax redirect the user via javascript, however these requests are being made many times in different areas of the application i'm working on, so it would be more maintainable if I could just handle this via php. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

I've read alot into some "post/redirect/get" questions here on stackoverflow however i'm not sure if that is a workable approach in this situation. Any tips would be great!

Comment: You can send a redirect in response to POST.

Comment: You have the `ajax` tag. If you're using AJAX, you have to do the redirect in JavaScript. The redirect is just used to get the AJAX response, it doesn't affect the user's page.

Comment: Hi there! I've tried using header() as well as the 302 and 303 status codes to respond with a redirect, however the browser doesn't seem to process this.

Comment: Unfortunately, without using javascript, it's not possible for a sub-request (such as ajax) to cause the window to navigate to a different URL. You could have the request submit a form instead, which would allow a full redirect, or setup a [global ajax event handler](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) (or just share the same ajax code) to handle a programmatic redirect when appropriate.